# wait for specifed time without using while C

Tags: c, linux

I'm wondering how to make a time delay of a few seconds using C , without using while loop. The samples I got are using while loop. 
This works but I dont want to use the while loop. Please help

```
while(clock() < endwaitTime)
    {
        if(!GetFlag())
        {
            print(" Canceled ");
            return ; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: sleep? usleep? see man 3 sleep

Comment: call a system function like sleep() or select()

Comment: yeah select would be the real world way to go, in the context of wait x time, or return if there is something to do.

Comment: Sorry missed this line endwait = clock() + (waitTime * CLOCKS_PER_SEC)/1000 ; //convert millisecond to sec which is before while loop

Comment: Do you *really* want to get rid of while() or only reduce the CPU usage from 100% to something reasonable?

Comment: I dont want to get rid of while as it keep polling. Which is not good option for my app

Comment: The correct way to do this depends on how `GetFlag` works.  Does it check something which might be set by a signal handler?  Do some user or network I/O?

Comment: @aschepler Yes, that can be a real problem.  I assumed it was a non-blocking polling function, but that might not be true,

Comment: Would it be possible to modify the function that **sets** the flag `GetFlag()` is testing?

Comment: yes, please let me know ur suggestion to test

Comment: You probably need to post the code to GetFlag(), and anything called by GetFlag(), and possibly whatever sets the flag, to get a better answer to this...

Comment: Learn about [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) syscall and read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Comment: @Paul I m just checking on net, can i use pthread_cond_timedwait. What you  say?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sleep()` to pause your application for the given amount of seconds, or you can use `usleep()` to pause your application for the given amount of microseconds.

You can also explore the blocking properties of `select()` to have a microsecond precision pausing. Some applications prefer to do that, don't ask me why.

About your `while()` loop, never do that. It is not pausing. Your application will loop using 99% of the CPU until the time has elapsed. Its a very dumb way of doing that.

Also, its preferable that you use `time()` to get the current UNIX time and use that  as reference, and `difftime()` to get the time delta in seconds to use with `sleep()`.

You may have problems with `clock()`, because this function on a 32-bit system will return the same number every ~72 minutes, and you will often have a `endwaitTime` with lower value than the current return value of `clock()`.

Comment: I think usleep is micro seconds, where u looks like the lower case y-u looking Greek nu/mu thingy that means 1e-6.

Comment: Agreed that why i want to get rid of while loop. But if I use time() with difftime() how will I keep checking for my flag. I am really dumb on this

Comment: Well, you can loop with `usleep(100000)`, you application will check the flag 10 times per second, but the loop won't take full CPU. You could also explore the use of `signal()` to resume the process when a event happens, but thats a whole new topic.

Comment: If I simply want to use usleep(100000) then how should I check for my flag. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Following http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep

```
#include <unistd.h>
...
// note clock() is seconds of CPU time, but we will sleep and not use CPU time
// therefore clock() is not useful here ---
// Instead expiration should be tested with time(), which gives the "date/time" in secs
// since Jan 1, 1970
long int expiration = time()+300 ; // 5 minutes = 300 secs.  Change this as needed.
while(time() < expiration)
    {   
        sleep(2); // dont chew up CPU time, but check every 2 seconds

        if(!GetFlag())
        {
            print(" Canceled ");
            return ; 
        }
    }
...
```

Of course, you can get rid of the while loop completely if a single sleep() is good enough.  For a short pause this may be OK.  Input is still queued by Linux while the process is sleeping, and will be delivered to the stdin of the program when it wakes up from the sleep.

Comment: Sorry missed this line endwait = clock() + (waitTime * CLOCKS_PER_SEC)/1000 ; //convert millisecond to sec

Comment: How long do you want it to loop, waiting for input? How often do you want it to check?

Comment: I dont want it to loop. It need to wait till the user entered time or if cancelflag is set

Comment: Ah. Well, select(), which is more complex, can be used to wake up either after a certain time OR when input occurs. It is not clear to me if this can replace part of GetFlag(), or even what GetFlag() does [e.g. is it non-blocking?].

Comment: Alternatively, you can interrupt a sleep with a signal, which will then need a signal handler.  This may be more than you want to mess with for a simple program. The issue here would be: what generates the signal?

Comment: GetFlag is just to check the value of a var, which defines that user want to cancel the wait and move .